# Huawei switch Hybrid port

Tags: switch

i am trying to understand when we can use hybrid ports on a huawei switch. i understand the difference between Trunk and Hybrid port, but so far I've been unable to find a scenario where i can see and understand better the use of Hybrid ports.

what i know:

hybrid ports can carry multiple untagged vlan traffic, while trunk ports can only carry untagged traffic for the default vlan.

Can anyone enlighten me where one can use a hybrid port?

Comment: Very few, oddball situations. That you cannot think of any is a Good Thing(tm).

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: A "hybrid port" is a port that carries untagged traffic of multiple VLANs. What Ricky means it that there are very few, very specific situations this is useful, which is shown by the fact that you can't think of any. I've been trying to figure it out now for a few years and still haven't found out. I've been told that this can be used when you're daisy-chaining a PC to an IP phone that doesn't support dot1Q VLAN tagging - but I've never seen a phone like that, and I've yet to meet a person who has. So if you don't know you need it, don't bother with it, is my advice :)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably im not 100% right but from my point of view a hybrid port is either an access or trunk. you dont have to specify it when you configure the port, by just adding the vlans to the the port, the port will act as trunk or access.

Answer (score 1):

imagine you want to seperate ipv4 and ipv6 traffic with different vlans,

you could use protocol based vlans (ethernetii etype 806) on hybrid ports.

since they're carrying two untagged vlans no further configuration is neccesary.

/j

Comment: So this'd be useful if you want for example a server have both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, and you want to as you say separate the traffic on the backbone. Thanks jKnz, that's the first answer I've seen that makes sense.